# How to Repeat signature horizontally based on Characters in aspose.word

Tags: asp.net, aspose, aspose.words

We have a word document with [Signature] Key as a paragraph, All we need to do is replace with signature with some Names, based on the names we need to repeat the [signature] key.

```
Ex: if names are containing 10 to 15 characters  it should be repeat 2 times in a row like below

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  


if names are containing 5 charecters should be repeat 3 times

XXXXXXXXXXXXXX            XXXXXXXXXXXXXX       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

based on the name node will repeat...?

please help how to solve this task ......
```

Comment: I am social media developer at Aspose. Do you want to repeat the same name 2 and 3 times in a file where [Signature] key is present? Elaborate your requirement abit so a proper solution can be shared.

Comment: @NausherwanAslam Not same names it is different names based on names i need to repeat the [Signature].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find and replace text in a word document, Aspose.Words provides IReplacingCallback interface which can easily be used to achieve your goal. I used a static string to test the scenario as I don't have the details of your data source. You will require to add a check in your code based on the name length, you need to add the signature. Check the following sample:

```
//Open the file
Document doc = new Document("c:\\data\\Signature.docx");

//Specify the string / tag to be replace 
doc.Range.Replace(new Regex(@"\[Signature\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase), new ReplaceEvaluatorSignature(), false);

//Save the updated document
doc.Save("c:\\data\\Output.docx");



 /// <summary>
/// Class to change the signature 
/// </summary>
public class ReplaceEvaluatorSignature : IReplacingCallback
{

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called by the Aspose.Words find and replace engine for each match.
    /// This method highlights the match string, even if it spans multiple runs.
    /// </summary>
    ReplaceAction IReplacingCallback.Replacing(ReplacingArgs e)
    {

        // This is a Run node that contains either the beginning or the complete match.
        Node currentNode = e.MatchNode;

        // The first (and may be the only) run can contain text before the match,
        // in this case it is necessary to split the run.
        if (e.MatchOffset > 0)

            currentNode = SplitRun((Run)currentNode, e.MatchOffset);

        // This array is used to store all nodes of the match for further removing.
        ArrayList runs = new ArrayList();

        // Find all runs that contain parts of the match string.
        int remainingLength = e.Match.Value.Length;
        while (
            (remainingLength > 0) &&

            (currentNode != null) &&

            (currentNode.GetText().Length <= remainingLength))
        {

            runs.Add(currentNode);

            remainingLength = remainingLength - currentNode.GetText().Length;

            // Select the next Run node.
            // Have to loop because there could be other nodes such as BookmarkStart etc.

            do
            {

                currentNode = currentNode.NextSibling;

            }

            while ((currentNode != null) && (currentNode.NodeType != NodeType.Run));

        }





        // Split the last run that contains the match if there is any text left.
        if ((currentNode != null) && (remainingLength > 0))
        {

            SplitRun((Run)currentNode, remainingLength);

            runs.Add(currentNode);

        }

        //Name is defined for testing, replace it with your data source
       // string TestName = "Nausherwan Aslam";

        //Following is to test less or equal to 10 charators
        string TestName = "Nausherwan";

        // Create Document Buidler 
        DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(e.MatchNode.Document as Document);

        builder.MoveTo((Run)runs[runs.Count - 1]);

        if (TestName.Length > 10)
        {
            builder.Write(TestName+ "        " +  TestName);
        }
        else
        {
            builder.Write(TestName + "          " + TestName + "         " + TestName);
        }
        // Now remove all runs in the sequence.
        foreach (Run run in runs)
            run.Remove();

        // Signal to the replace engine to do nothing because we have already done all what we wanted.
        return ReplaceAction.Skip;

    }

    private static Run SplitRun(Run run, int position)
    {

        Run afterRun = (Run)run.Clone(true);

        afterRun.Text = run.Text.Substring(position);

        run.Text = run.Text.Substring(0, position);

        run.ParentNode.InsertAfter(afterRun, run);

        return afterRun;

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your replay it is working but need to repeat different names not same name as you done in above...

Comment: Can you give the details regarding your data source e.g. array, list etc. this will help me in understanding the issue and assit you.

Comment: thanks for your replay I got the solution.. i used Parameterized constructor to pass the values.